# android activity with fragments exits when orientation of the device is changed

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app consists of one activity made up of two fragments. The first fragment is added through XML and the second fragment is added dynamically depending on the inputs from the first fragment. The app works perfectly on the emulator. But when tested on a real device (Samsung galaxy tab) the app simply exits upon changing the device orientation (without crashing and without any errors). I'm using android 4.0. I searched for this problem a lot and tried out the various solutions given on this site and others, but the problem persists. I would also like to add that the version of my app which does not use fragments works fine on both orientations.

the main layout file (activity_main.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment 
android:name="androiapps.autoqos.FirstFragment"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp" 
/>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout" >

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnInputReceivedListener, MessageSendListener{
//variable declarations 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onConfirm(Bundle bundle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(bundle!=null){
        //int PT = bundle.getInt("PT");
        System.out.println("Got:"+bundle.getString("ip")+bundle.getString("port")+bundle.getString("tcpip")
                +bundle.getString("tcpport")+bundle.getInt("PT",0));
        udpHost=bundle.getString("ip");
        udpPort=bundle.getString("port");
        tcpHost=bundle.getString("tcpip");
        tcpPort=bundle.getString("tcpport");
        pType=bundle.getInt("pType",0);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        MessageFragment fragment = new MessageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void send(Bundle bundle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(bundle==null)
        return;

    msg = bundle.getString("msg");
    delay = bundle.getInt("delay",0);
    System.out.println("Got: "+msg+delay);          
    startTransmission();
}
void startTransmission(){
    System.out.println("\nTrying to send data");
    sendFilter = new IntentFilter(UdpResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP1);
    sendFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    receiver1 = new UdpResponseReceiver(); 
    receiveFilter = new IntentFilter(UdpHandlerReceiver.ACTION_RESP2);
    receiveFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    receiver2 = new UdpHandlerReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver1, sendFilter);
    registerReceiver(receiver2, receiveFilter);
    udpServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UdpSendService.class);
    udpReceiveIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UdpReceiveService.class);
    udpServiceIntent.putExtra("host",udpHost);
    udpServiceIntent.putExtra("port", udpPort);
    udpServiceIntent.putExtra("msg",msg);
    udpServiceIntent.putExtra("delay",delay);
    udpServiceIntent.putExtra("pType",pType);
    startService(udpServiceIntent);
    udpReceiveIntent.putExtra("tcpHost", tcpHost);
    udpReceiveIntent.putExtra("tcpPort", tcpPort);
    startService(udpReceiveIntent);
}
public class UdpResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION_RESP1 = "com.example.udpmessageclient.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Update UI, new "message" processed by SimpleIntentService
        System.out.println(intent.getStringExtra(UdpSendService.PARAM_OUT_MSG));

    }      
}   
public class UdpHandlerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION_RESP2 = "com.example.udpmessageclient.intent.action.MESSAGE_RECEIVED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Update UI, new "message" processed by SimpleIntentService
        System.out.println("Received message from server: "+intent.getStringExtra(UdpReceiveService.OUT_MSG));

    }    
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    endTransmission();
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm);
    btn.setEnabled(true);

}
void endTransmission(){
    UdpSendService.send=false;
    if(receiver1!=null && receiver2!=null){
        unregisterReceiver(receiver1);
        unregisterReceiver(receiver2);
        receiver1=null;
        receiver2=null;
    }
    //while(stopService(udpReceiveIntent)!=true);
    if(udpReceiveIntent!=null)
        stopService(udpReceiveIntent);
    System.out.println("\nreceive service stopped");
    //while(stopService(udpServiceIntent)!=true);
    if(udpServiceIntent!=null)
        stopService(udpServiceIntent);
    System.out.println("\nsend service stopped");
    return;
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(UdpSendService.send)
        stop();
    finish();

}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stop();
    finish();
}

    }
```

`FirstFragment.java`

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{
//variable declarations
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_message_form, null);
    contentView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    text1 = (EditText) contentView.findViewById(R.id.ip);
    text2 = (EditText) contentView.findViewById(R.id.port);
    text3 = (EditText) contentView.findViewById(R.id.tcpip);
    text4 = (EditText) contentView.findViewById(R.id.tcpport);
    if(onSaveInstance!=null){
        text1.setText(onSaveInstance.getString("ip"));
        text2.setText(onSaveInstance.getString("port"));
        text3.setText(onSaveInstance.getString("tcpip"));
        text4.setText(onSaveInstance.getString("tcpport"));
    }
    button= (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm);
    rb1 = (RadioButton) contentView.findViewById(R.id.rbtn_1);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) contentView.findViewById(R.id.rbtn_2);
    rb3 = (RadioButton) contentView.findViewById(R.id.rbtn_3);
    rb4 = (RadioButton) contentView.findViewById(R.id.rbtn_4);
    confirmButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            button.setEnabled(false);
            if (rb1.isChecked())
                PT = 0;
            else if (rb2.isChecked())
                PT = 1;
            else if (rb3.isChecked())
                PT = 2;
            else if (rb4.isChecked())
                PT = 3;
            else
                PT = 0;
            ip = text1.getText().toString().trim();
            port = text2.getText().toString().trim();
            tcpip=text3.getText().toString().trim();
            tcpport=text4.getText().toString().trim();
            if(ip=="" || port=="" || tcpip == "" || tcpport ==""){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please fill in all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("ip",ip);
                b.putString("port", port);
                b.putString("tcpip",tcpip);
                b.putString("tcpport", tcpport);
                b.putInt("pType", PT);

                if ( listener != null ){
                    System.out.println("Bundle:"+ip+port+tcpip+tcpport+PT);
                    listener.onConfirm(b);
                }
            }
            }
    };
    return contentView;
}
@Override
public void onStart(){
super.onStart();
button.setOnClickListener(confirmButtonListener);
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onAttach(activity);
try {
    listener = (OnInputReceivedListener)activity;
}catch (ClassCastException e) {
    Toast.makeText( activity, "Activity must implement this interface.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
public interface OnInputReceivedListener{
    public void onConfirm(Bundle bundle);
}
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    onSaveInstance = new Bundle();
    onSaveInstance.putString("udpHost", ip);
    onSaveInstance.putString("udpPort", port);
    onSaveInstance.putString("tcpHost", tcpip);
    onSaveInstance.putString("tcpPort", tcpport);

}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(onSaveInstance!=null){
        text1.setText(onSaveInstance.getString("ip"));
        text2.setText(onSaveInstance.getString("port"));
        text3.setText(onSaveInstance.getString("tcpip"));
        text4.setText(onSaveInstance.getString("tcpport"));
    }
}
}
```

`MessageFragment.java`

```
public class MessageFragment extends Fragment{
//variable declarations
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_message, null);
    contentView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    msgText = (EditText) contentView.findViewById(R.id.msg);
    sendBtn = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    stopBtn = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
    if(onSaveInstance!=null){
        msgText.setText(onSaveInstance.getString("msg"));
        delayField.setText(onSaveInstance.getInt("delay", 0));
    }
    b = getArguments();
    System.out.println("PT="+b.getInt("pType",0));
    if(b!=null){
        int pType = b.getInt("pType");
        if(pType==1 || pType== 3){
            delayField = (EditText) contentView.findViewById(R.id.delay);
            tvDelay = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.tvDelay);
            tvDelay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            delayField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    sendButtonListener=new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sendBtn.setEnabled(false);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            msg=msgText.getText().toString();
            delay=Integer.parseInt(delayField.getText().toString());
            b.putString("msg", msg);
            if(delayField!=null)
                b.putInt("delay",delay);
            if(mListener!=null)
                mListener.send(b);
        }
    };
    stopButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sendBtn.setEnabled(true);
            mListener.stop();
        }
    };
    return contentView;
}
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(sendButtonListener);
    stopBtn.setOnClickListener(stopButtonListener);
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (MessageSendListener)activity;
    }catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Toast.makeText( activity, "Activity must implement this interface.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public interface MessageSendListener{
    public void send(Bundle bundle);
    public void stop();
}
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    onSaveInstance = new Bundle();
    onSaveInstance.putString("msg", msg);
    onSaveInstance.putInt("delay", delay);
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(onSaveInstance!=null){
        msgText.setText(onSaveInstance.getString("msg"));
        delayField.setText(onSaveInstance.getInt("delay", 0));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: simple exits no logcat error  anything ?

Comment: @PoonamAnthony did you add the code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stop();
    finish();
```

Why finish()?  Your app is doing exactly what you coded it to do.  When the orientation changes, onStop() is called.  You then `finish()` your activity.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i shall remove `finish()` from `onStop()`. but it would still cause the activity to restart isn't it? how can prevent that or maybe make it retain the values entered before the orientation was changed?

Comment: i would like to handle the orientation change within the fragments. since thats where i am taking input from the user. presently i am just overriding the `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods within the fragments to save the input values. I dont know if this is the correct way.

Comment: It is the correct way.  The Android way is to manage state during configuration changes or app going to the background using onPause()/onStop() and onResume()/onStart() depending on your workflow.  Whether it makes sense to do that in your parent Activity or within the fragments is down to your needs/style/design.  Personally, I like to handle everything in the Activity, usually as a matter of style, so I know that all state management is in the same consistent place.

Comment: i read in the android documentation that a fragment's lifecycle is closely connected to its parent activity's lifecycle. So when the onStop() method of the activity is called, then the fragment's onStop() method is called. Maybe i should override onStop() method of the fragments as well. Since, it will be called when orientation is changed.The reason why I am handling the state management of the fragments is because I need to access the views declared within the fragment. could you tell me how to access them from the parent activity as well?

Comment: Thanks a lot.removing finish() from onStop() solved the problem of exiting. but now some new errors have cropped up.maybe i am not handling the activity states correctly

Comment: You're welcome.  If you have a new problem you can't solve, start another question.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Did you use this code

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

For more info check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: I added it in the manifest file within the activity tag. hope its the correct way of using it?

Comment: @PoonamAnthony you have to add in same order..keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation

Comment: No there is no error in the logcat. The app does not crash. it simply exits and starts again when I start it manually

Comment: Did you add the above code in each and every activity tag in manifest

Comment: no i havent got my answer yet.but thanks for your time and help